# Python priorities between different lists

Tags: python-3.x

So i was wondering whether there is a way to implement a priority between lists. Like for example:

```
a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4']
b = ['b1','b2','b3','b4']
user_input ='b1,a1,a2,b3'
```

So user_input is pretty much what the user has enter as a sequence of tasks, if we consider the elements inside of the lists as 'tasks'.My question is how can i make the programm interpret that tasks from list b have a higher priority than tasks from list a, therefore when the user enters the following sequence from above it will be executed in the following order: b1,b3,a1,a2.
A similar example could probably be given with a elevator, where the pushed from inside buttons have a higher priority in contrast to those, outside the elevator. I would like the output to a list, which saves the correct order:

```
list_result = ['b1','b3','a1','a2']
```

This is just an example, the real one would probably save more then 100 different tasks. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` to do this. Essentially, the `key` for how to sort the `list` (got by splitting `user_input` on a `,`) is just if the element is `in` the highest priority `list` (`a`). This works as a `key` of `True` brings an element towards the front of a list and `False` to the back.

This can all be done in a neat one-liner:

```
list_result = sorted(user_input.split(','), key=lambda s: s in a)
```

which gives the intended output of:

```
['b1', 'b3', 'a1', 'a2']
```

Comment: In that case wouldn't s in a return False, therefore moving 'b1' to the back of the list? Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @zauahiri Python considers `True` > `False` and, by default, the result of sorting is in ascending order, so from small to big. Therefore `False` comes before `True`.

Comment: @Thijs van Dien  I falsely thought that it first sorts the original list and then splits, which makes no sense whatsoever. Thanks again!

Comment: @zauahiri Please accept (grey --> green tick next to the answer) thank you!